# Are those two filters equal?

Tags: filter, feedback

Are those two filters equal to each other in their functionality? Of not, what is the difference between them mathematically speaking (zeros, poles, etc)? Also, what is the difference in their function?

Essentially I want to simplify the op-amp filter to something without active components. And I wanted to ask around and see if I got it right.

Note: the selection of components is only for illustration, and the op-amp can be any other pamp model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSObr6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is this a serious question?

Comment: Sometime, I have my coffee in the AM and really want to troll around people on SE. Yes! It is serious.

Comment: I am trying to simplify the filter with the op-amp, and wanted to see if I am doing it right. So that is why I wanted to ask it.

Comment: Is that op amp circuit actually in use as a filter somewhere? If so, that's a pretty dangerous.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul, have you looked at the Sallen-Key type filters.

Comment: There is no positive feedback in that circuit.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean R5 anc C6 in reverse order in the top circuit?  It would then actually make some sense.

Comment: The op-amp circuit is plainly wrong.

Comment: The opamp is what I have to work with, and it is the one I tried to simplifiy on the top circuit. If the top one is wrong,  it is because of my wrong understand of it.

Comment: Question: Can a circuit be "wrong"? Rather, I think it is - technically spoken - better to say that a circuit cannot serve the intended needs. By the way: The active circuit is a PI controller to be used in many negative feedback systems. But agreed: Without dc feedback and due to real opamp behaviour the circuit will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement Olin's answer on why this is impossible with only passives:

The frequency response for the op-amp circuit is (assuming an ideal op-amp with negative feedback):
\begin{equation}
G = \frac{-i (C_3 R_2 \omega - i)}{C_3 R_2 \omega (C_4 R_1 \omega - i)}
\end{equation}

With the transfer function in s space of:
\begin{equation}
G = \frac{C_3 R_2 s + 1}{C_3 R_2 s (C_4 R_1 s + 1)}
\end{equation}

Notice that you will have a pole at \$s = 0\$ (with 1 other pole and 1 other zero). This is a constant amplitude component which relies on the greater than 1 gain of the Op-Amp (for my model the gain tends to infinity). However, passive networks can't have any gain greater than 1 by definition because they can't introduce net energy into the circuit. Thus this filter response can never be reconstructed using passives.

Here's the frequency response of the op-amp filter:
[image]

If we ignore low frequency part and only consider the high frequency response, you effectively have a first order RC low pass filter with a cutoff frequency of about \$10^6 \frac{rad}{s}\$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two circuits don't have the same response, not even close.  This should be obvious from casual inspection.  Clearly the top circuit can't have gain higher than 1.  However, the bottom circuit has a high pass filter in the feedback loop, so will have gain exceeding 1 for low frequencies.  In fact, the gain is whatever the open loop gain of the opamp is at DC.

There is no need to go further than this.  Again, from casual inspection, obviously, the two circuits have different responses.

Comment: What would be the closest passive circuit to the one with the op-amp?

Comment: @Kingsi: There isn't one.  Again, the opamp circuit has significant gain, which a passive circuit isn't going to do.

Comment: If we drop the gain considerations?

Comment: @Kingsi: This is getting silly.  If you drop enough requirements for similarity, you can make a puppy dog look like a tomato too.  You asked a question and it was answered.  Perhaps you need to ask a different question that is actually what you want to know.

Comment: Wow, thanks for nothing I guess. Are you here to help and discuss? Or to collect points for answers? And as far as being as strict as you are, my original question was more than are they the same - because a blind man can see they are not. The original question also was, **what is the difference between them *mathematically* speaking (*zeros*, *poles*, etc)? Also, what is the difference in their function?**

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul What the responders are saying is that the op-amp circuit is wrong. Having practically "infinite" gain at DC it will likely set the output close to +/-15V, so the equivalent circuit would be to connect the output to the power rail. Hence, the derision and general amusement at your question. On your "mathematically speaking" point, any AC analysis is mute if the circuit does not reach an equilibrium DC operating point, and yours will not.

Comment: I wouldn`t say that the second (active) part of the circuit is "wrong", because it is one of the most used controller in feedback systems (PI controller). However, due to missing dc feedback it works only as a part of an overall closed circuit with negative feedback.